# Can I use thread in userControl to prevent hanging while application is running?

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, user-controls

I have designed a *WPF* in *C#*. `userControl` class contains a method (it called `MainProgram`) that computes expensive operations. In order to prevent hanging UI when the application is running, I decided to use threads. I want to use the *Task-based Asynchronous Pattern* (**TAP**) along with `async`-`await` keywords.

here is pseudocode of the algorithm:

```
private void StartSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBoxLog.AppendText("Program Start");
    globalSetter();
    MainProgram();  
}
```

In the program, the user should fill the form (includes some `textBox`) in the UI and then click on `StartSearch` button to run the `MainProgram` until the output shown in the `textBox`. As specified in the pseudocode, at this time, a message in a UI showed to the user that the program starts. Then `globalSetter` method, set all the global parameters that the user filled from the UI. With those parameters, `MainProgram` starts to run (it is a heavy method) and take a few minutes to run. While MainProgram is running, it deals with UI by showing messages to the user in a `textBox`!

So, the question is how can I use TAB to prevent hanging UI when the application is running? thanks for all answers.

Comment: @vasily.sib you can see the pseudocode. please describe me How can I run the code in another thread using TAP? If my implementation is wrong, tell how to fix it? tnx

Comment: It's ups to you. I think moderators somehow will find this question someday, and mark it for deletion. Or maybe some new SO user will write some code for you to get some rep:\

Answer (score 1):

You can find more information about the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP) on the MSDN. I would suggest reading the whole page, Tasks can bring sometimes nasty bugs or other problems. You should understand it completly before using.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap

You can execute code in a new Task with

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    Console.WriteLine("Hello Task");
});
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but I received an error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'comboBoxLanguage' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'
It occurs when globalSetter method is running.